# Migrate teamcity pipeline to gitlab

Tags: migration, gitlab-ci, teamcity, pipeline

How to migrate a teamcity pipeline to gitlab?
I checked online and could only find integration related stuff.
Please advise

Comment: This is so off-topic you have shared no example of a pipeline for anyone to even comment nor have you shown any attempt at solving the issue.

Comment: @ChrisDoyle: I'm looking at a generic solution to migrate any pipeline from teamcity to gitlab. Say, I have 10-20 pipelines in teamcity

Comment: There isn't a tool that will just convert them for you, each pipeline could have various levels of complexity and requirements, you wont get a generic solution. I have just gone through a large CI migration from Atlassian Bamboo to gitlab. You just need to bite the bullet and migrate them one by one and test them properly.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisDoyle. Could you please share some useful references for gitlab ci/cd pipeline design

Comment: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/quick_start/

Comment: @chrisDoyle: In gitlab, every single step is a script? Say if we want to execute "mvn clean test", the mvn executable should be present in the gitlab project . Meaning there is no pre-defined for well known types

Comment: it can be a script or a collection of commands, you can have before_script, script, after_script, each job is run independent of another, jobs may run on different runners etc. The docs are a good source for most questions

Comment: why do you need to migrate from tc to gl?